# Reading a Tree from a Separate File

Tags: c++, histogram, root-framework

I am working with C++ and ROOT.
I created a simple tree in a separate .C file/code (called tree_ex1.c) and I am trying to get the contents of that tree and plot a histogram in another .C file (called tree_ex2.c). 
I expect that with using the tree_ex1.c if I plot the histogram of one of the variables in the tree it will be the same histogram that I would plot with my second .C file, tree_ex2.c

In my tree_ex1.c file, I created a simple tree and I plotted the histogram of one of the tree's branches. I am able to get a histogram from the tree_ex1.c. Then, in my tree_ex2.c file, I am trying to call the contents of the my tree in the first file to plot the same variable.  However, my histogram from the tree_ex2.c does not look the same.

Below is my attempt. I get a plot that basically looks empty. The number of entries is 10000 but the mean and standard deviation is 0.

```
void tree_ex2()
{ 


  //Filling Histograms
  //TH1F *hist = new TH1F("hist", "", 100, 0., 2.); (worked)
  TH2F *h_pxpy = new TH2F("h_pxpy", "py Vs px", 100, -2.0, 2.0, 100, -2.0, 2.0);
  TH1F *h_pt = new TH1F("h_pt", "pt", 100, 0., 5.0);


  TFile *f = new TFile("new.root"); //new.root is name of file that was "RECREATED" in tree_ex1
  //TFile *f = TFile::Open("new.root"); 
  TTree *tree1 = (TTree*) f->Get("T"); 
    //Set up the variables
  Float_t px, py, pz, pt;
  Double_t random;
  Int_t i;

    //Set Variables to Tree's Branches

  tree1->Branch("px", &px);
  tree1->Branch("py", &py);
  tree1->Branch("pz", &pz);
  tree1->Branch("pt", &pt);
  tree1->Branch("random", &random);

  Int_t nentries = (Int_t)tree1->GetEntries();

  for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    tree1->GetEntry(i);

    h_pxpy->Fill(px, py);
    h_pt->Fill(pt);
  }

  TCanvas *c1 = new TCanvas();
  h_pxpy->Draw("colz");
  //c1->SaveAs("tree_example2_pxpy.png");

  TCanvas *c2 = new TCanvas();
  //c1->Update();
  h_pt->Draw();
  //c2->SaveAs("tree_example2_pt.png");

  //f->Write();
  f->Close();

}
```

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're mistaking `Branch` for `SetBranchAddress` in the code you posted. The documentation of Branch says (e.g. https://root.cern/doc/master/classTTree.html#ab47499eeb7793160b20fa950f4de716a) "Add a new branch". While you want to read from an existing branch. https://root.cern/doc/master/classTTree.html#a39b867210e4a77ef44917fd5e7898a1d.

So I think if you replace

```cpp
  tree1->Branch("px", &px);
  tree1->Branch("py", &py);
  tree1->Branch("pz", &pz);
  tree1->Branch("pt", &pt);
  tree1->Branch("random", &random);
```

by

```cpp
  tree1->SetBranchAddress("px", &px);
  tree1->SetBranchAddress("py", &py);
  tree1->SetBranchAddress("pz", &pz);
  tree1->SetBranchAddress("pt", &pt);
  tree1->SetBranchAddress("random", &random);
```

That should give you the desired result.

(unrelated, `TFile::Open` is recommended over `new TFile` because it can also handle non-local files, see the comment  https://root.cern/doc/master/classTFile.html#ad0377adf2f3d88da1a1f77256a140d60. This doesn't gain you anything here, but is considered good practice.)